# При закрытии приложения методом Application.Terminate возникает ошибка

Tags: delphi, исключения

При закрытии приложения методом `Application.Terminate` возникает ошибка:

> First chance exception at $00409959. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00409959: read of address 0x00000024'. Process Prog.exe (10940)
>
> В системном файле (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\source\rtl\sys\System.pas:17175) :

```
procedure TMonitor.Destroy;
begin
  if (MonitorSupport <> nil) and (FLockEvent <> nil) then //Ошибка
    MonitorSupport.FreeSyncObject(FLockEvent);
  FreeMem(@Self);
end;
```

Возникает ошибка при доступе к FLockEvent, т.к он не существует.

Как решить эту проблему ?
В проекте было добавлено: работа с idHttp и Json

P.S. 1 Ошибка возникает при освобождения самой формы(не главной), после удаления всех элементов с формы.
P.S. 2 Стек вызова:

```
System.TMonitor.Destroy
System.TMonitor.Destroy(???)
System.TObject.CleanupInstance
System.TObject.FreeInstance
System._ClassDestroy(???)
Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Destroy
System.TObject.Free
System.Classes.TComponent.DestroyComponents
Vcl.Forms.DoneApplication
System.SysUtils.DoExitProc
System._Halt0
:00409043 TObject.Free + $B
:76d138f4 KERNEL32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x24
:777156c3 ; 
:7771568e ;
```

В процессе вызова Monitor.Destroy; из class procedure TMonitor.Destroy(const AObject: TObject); Монитор имеет значения:

```
Watch Name      Value
Monitor     $18
FLockCount  Inaccessible value
FRecursionCount Inaccessible value
FOwningThread   Inaccessible value
FLockEvent  Inaccessible value
FSpinCount  Inaccessible value
FWaitQueue  Inaccessible value
FQueueLock  Inaccessible value
CacheLineSize   64 {$40}
FDefaultSpinCount   1000 {$3E8}
```

В итоге , даже если сначала удалить все пред формы, и оставить эту форму последней для удаления, ошибка все равно возникает. Компонентов в ней нет, они очищены.

Comment: нужно смотреть по стеку выше, кто вызывает этот код и понять, почему.

В целом, завершать приложение методом `Terminate` - не очень хорошая идея. Вы как бы говорите приложению - "все, завершайся. Будут ошибки - мне побоку". Поэтому, данное поведение в пределах ожидаемого.

Comment: @KoVadim Хорошо, а как нужно завершать приложение, которое имеет множество форм?

Comment: `Winapi.Windows.PostQuitMessage(ExitCode)`

Comment: Нужно закрыть MainForm.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Возникает та же самая ошибка. (форма не может удалиться)

Comment: @KoVadim при закрытии главной формы, происходит то же самое. Видимо, если данную форму перенести в другой проект, то она корректно закрывается.

Comment: тогда Вам нужно показать больше кода или стектрейс

Comment: Почему вы используете метод Application.Terminate?

Comment: @androschuk Чтобы закрыть приложение, если не показана главная форма. (из формы авторизации)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенос объектов из полей формы в глобальные (как показано в ответе автора вопроса), проблему решает либо по чистой случайности, либо по совершенно монструозному дизайну.

Ошибка вызвана повторным вызовом `TMonitor.Destroy;`. Кем и как именно он вызывается - надо смотреть по вашему коду.

Comment: я думаю, что это особенность XE6, потому как деструктор TJsonObject я не вызываю, в XE10 данный проект без ошибок завершается.

Comment: @АнатолийХлебников Скорее всего, это не особенность XE6, а особенность скомпилированного кода, который по случайности в ХЕ6 располагается в памяти так, что происходит ошибка, а в 10 Seattle - иначе, и ошибка проскакивает незамеченной.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решилась тем, что я отключил сначала FJSONObject: TJSONObject , после ошибка исчезла. В итоге проблема крылась в

```
type
 TForm8 = class(TForm)
private
    { Private declarations }
    FJSONObject: TJSONObject;
```

А нужно было

```
type
 TForm8 = class(TForm)
private
    { Private declarations }
public
    { Public declarations }
end;

var
    FJSONObject: TJSONObject;
```

Comment: Может лучше бы определить место где идет обращение к `FJSONObject` и `if Assigned(FJSONObject )...` чем делать глобальную переменную?

Comment: @androschuk Да вы правы. Но когда я брал пример, там было именно в глобальной секции.

Comment: @АнатолийХлебников А это значит, что вы не понимаете, как работает код из примера и пытаетесь его использовать для своих задач. Это очень плохая практика.

Comment: @zed Почему же сразу не понимаю, код работает как надо. Но почему тогда его нельзя расположить в private формы ? Я не вызывал его деструктор.

Comment: @АнатолийХлебников Я вашего кода не вижу, поэтому не могу ответить на вопрос "Почему?". Но тот факт, что вы, имея код перед глазами, задаётесь этим вопросом, как раз и говорит о том, что вы не понимаете, как он работает. Тут нет абсолютно никакой магии - объекты можно располагать в глобальной области видимости, а можно в локальной. Всё зависит от их назначения. Соответственно, и использовать такие объекты нужно по разному. И если вы перенесли объект из одной области видимости в другую, вам нужно исправлять и остальной код, использующий его, чего вы, судя по всему, и не сделали.

Comment: @АнатолийХлебников Как вариант, можно поискать все места где идет обращение к `FJSONObject` и определить вызов идет внутри класса TForm8 или нет, если нет - переписать реализацию.